Efficient masked argsort in Numpy
I have a numpy array such as this one:
arr = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, -5, 6],
    [-1, -1, -1]
])

And I would like to argsort it, but with a arr <= 0 mask. The output should be:
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 2],       # (Note that the indices are still relative to original un-masked array)
       []])

However, the output I get using np.ma.argsort() is:
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 2, 1],
       [0, 1, 2]])

The approach needs to be very efficient because the real array has millions of columns. I am thinking this needs to be a synthesis of a few operations, but I don't know which ones.

ma.argsort just replaces the masked values will the fillvalue, and does a nornal argsort.  Since you want a different number of values for each row, some sort of row iteration will be required. Using the result will also require this iteration.

The np.where approach:
Input array
arr = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, -5, 6],
    [-1, -1, -1]
])

Mask of valid elements
mask = arr > 0

Preallocate result as an object array to hold variable-length indices
result = np.empty(arr.shape[0], dtype=object)

Efficient masked argsort for each row
for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
    valid_indices = np.where(mask[i])[0]  # Get indices of valid (masked) elements
    result[i] = valid_indices[np.argsort(arr[i, valid_indices])]  # Sort valid indices by their values

Output:
[array([0, 1, 2]) array([0, 2]) array([], dtype=int64)]

The np.flatnonzero approach:
A more optimised approach using vectorised operations:
def optimized_masked_argsort(arr, mask):
    result = np.empty(arr.shape[0], dtype=object)
    for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
        row = arr[i]
        valid_indices = np.flatnonzero(mask[i])  # Faster than np.where(mask[i])[0]
        valid_values = row[valid_indices]
        sorted_order = np.argsort(valid_values)
        result[i] = valid_indices[sorted_order]
    return result

Comparison:
Timings for given example:
np.where Time: 0.000034 seconds
np.flatnonzero Time: 0.000017 seconds

Timings for larger array (1000 rows):
np.where Time: 0.001856 seconds
np.flatnonzero Time: 0.001754 seconds

I tried a few other methods but they fell short in efficiency.
